# What 'memory total' actually means in yarn web UI

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

What does `memory total` represent in hadoop yarn web interface ?

Is it my total cluster capacity or is it something else? It is representing 48 GB under "memory total" for my cluster having 6 nodes. And also each node is showing 8GB only in available memory. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple `memory total` is `cluster capacity`. The rest can be explained using simple algebra.

```
 6 x 8 = 48
```

In a generic way :

```
memory_total = number_of_nodes x memory_of_each_node
```

Comment: No my cluster capacity in 1.56 TB. It is shown somewhere else. But i am not getting what do these 48 GB represent.

Comment: You should add this info to the question itself.